IF (OR (AND () function does not work as it should be
When I apply that command, for example P16 = 0.1, S16 = 0.1, it should output "Đ" but it outputs "KĐ". Please help me with this
=IF(OR(AND(P16<0,(P16<=R16)),AND(P16>=0,P16<=S16)),"Đ","KĐ")


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Is R16 a number?=ISNUMBER(R16) If not i.e. =FALSE, you might have peculiar effects of your formula.

Can you share the value of R16 thtat's also in the formula?

It outputs Đ. But it's likely a floating point issue for P16 or S16. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/floating-point-arithmetic-inaccurate-result

Do you not need to use XOR?

Testing that formula, P16 = 0.1, S16 = 0.1 returns "Đ".
There might be a rounding issue. 0.1 is a repeating binary in base 2. A calculation result may be displayed as "0.1" but get unexpected results when compared to 0.1.
Another cause for error might be a text cell that doesn't compare correctly.
For troubleshooting, split the formula temporarily and examine partial results for
=P16<0
=P16<=R16
=P16>=0
=P16<=S16

If rounding is a general problem, a good workaround is to work with 10x or 100x the desired values and divide by 10 or 100 for display only. E.g. instead of calculating dollars (with cents as decimal fraction), convert dollars to cents at the start, use cents throughout, and convert back to dollars at the end/for display.

1/10 in binary is very similar to 1/3 (decimal), i.e. with a forever repeating pattern of digits "after the comma", compare also to pi and e, two known irrational numbers -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrational_number

=IF(TEXT(P16,"0.0")="0.1", ... ) might also be a more precise "thing" here.

@Hannu That's another way to do it - I find working with tenth or hundredth less clumsy though.

There are positives and negatives with both.

You probably need to use an exclusive or XOR
Or(false, false) == false
Or(true, false) == true
Or(false, true) == true
Or(true, true) == true <

Using XOR
XOr(false, false) == false
XOr(true, false) == true
XOr(false, true) == true
XOr(true, true) == false <   

